# If form is submitted show div

Tags: jquery, html

I got a login button and when you click on it, the div with class .loginfields is shown. When you login, I want it to be shown as well. I can't figure out how this should be doen.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if($("#login").submit()) { function(e) {
             $(".loginfields").show();
        }}

        $(".loginfields").hide();
        $(".loginenable").show();

        $('.loginenable').click(function(){
           $(".loginfields").slideToggle();
        });
    });
</script>

<div class ="loginfields">
<form id="login" action="index.php" method="post">
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want to set the state appropriately with PHP when your page markup is rendered, however as you haven't shown any of your PHP code that's going to be tricky to help with

Comment: Set the display: css in php code? Or copy the entire .loginfields in the php? This results in duplicate code right..

Comment: Submitting a form reloads your page by default, so anything you do in javascript on this page, is irrelevant. You need to prevent the default action of the submit, by [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault), which stops the form submission, or switch to a php based solution.

Comment: Fixed it with a php solution even though this is not the prettiest solution. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to create an event handler:

```
$('#login').on('submit', function() {
    $(".loginfields").show();
});
```

If you're wanting your form submission to be dynamic, you'll need to look into [jQuery's `ajax()` method(s)](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to allow you to submit your forum without reloading the page (and with that you'd need to pass in the event into the function (that `(e)` you currently have), then call `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the browser attempting this for you).

Comment: This doesn't show the loginfields when it's submitted. Shouldn't it be in an if/else statement?

It doesn't have to be dynamic, just when the form is submitted and the page is reloaded (the form is processed on the same page) it should be instantly displayed.

Comment: This is an event handler. When your `#login` form receives its `submit` event, it will call `show()` on your `.loginfields` element. Calling `$('#login').submit()` attempts to submit the form with JavaScript there and then.

Answer (score 2):

You need to show the div on the form's `submit` event.

```
$("#login").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Stop submitting form
    $(".loginfields").show();
});
```